# Start new line shortcut doesn't work in Intellij IDEA 15

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Mac OS, I have mapped `Command + Shift` to `Start new line` and it works before.

But now, when I pressed the shortcut-key in the editor of IDEA I got no response. The error log is something like this: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current caret is defined, cannot operate on other ones.`

The details are:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current caret is defined, cannot operate on other ones
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl.runForEachCaret(CaretModelImpl.java:331)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl.runForEachCaret(CaretModelImpl.java:324)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.isEnabled(EditorActionHandler.java:81)
    at schemely.repl.toolwindow.actions.REPLEnterAction.isEnabled(REPLEnterAction.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.isEnabledForCaret(EditorActionHandler.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.isEnabled(EditorActionHandler.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actions.StartNewLineAction$Handler.isEnabledForCaret(StartNewLineAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.doIfEnabled(EditorActionHandler.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.access$000(EditorActionHandler.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler$2.perform(EditorActionHandler.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl$3.run(CaretModelImpl.java:342)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl.doWithCaretMerging(CaretModelImpl.java:422)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl.runForEachCaret(CaretModelImpl.java:333)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl.runForEachCaret(CaretModelImpl.java:324)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.isEnabled(EditorActionHandler.java:81)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.isEnabled(EditorActionHandler.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorAction.update(EditorAction.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorAction.updateForKeyboardAccess(EditorAction.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorAction.update(EditorAction.java:135)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction.beforeActionPerformedUpdate(AnAction.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:622)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.a(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:215)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:622)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2016-03-17 15:50:19,363 [3657174]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4  Build #IU-143.2287.1 
2016-03-17 15:50:19,363 [3657174]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_40-release 
2016-03-17 15:50:19,363 [3657174]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2016-03-17 15:50:19,363 [3657174]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2016-03-17 15:50:19,363 [3657174]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2016-03-17 15:50:19,363 [3657174]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: ShowSettings
```

Here are some discussions on the exception: [Multicaret problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206762365-Multicaret-problems).

---

Comments:

- It works fine since I installed it.
- The editor means the window where I edit my code, profiles, etc.
- I got those error once when I pressed the `Command + Shift` in the editor.
- I have forgotten when it didn't work any more...

**And thanks to @yole, I indeed got this problem by installing a third-part plugin named *schemely*.**

Comment: when does it work? what do you mean by editor? where do you use this shortcuts ' Shift + Command" and when do you get these error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a third-party plugin installed (schemely) which has an incorrect implementation of one of its actions, breaking the standard IntelliJ IDEA behavior. You can fix the issue by disabling the plugin.